file -i provide two different charsets for the same file on the same FS
I'm a bit confuse about a behavior of the file -i command. I searched a while and give up since I didn't have a sufficient knowledge regarding encoding as well as linux file command (to stay concise about my lack of knowledge...).
The situation is the following one:

Considering a file sample-input.xml store behind /a/specific/path/in/the/fs.
Considering the shell current working directory as /a/specific/path.

Commands:

First case


Command: /a/specific/path/$ file -i /a/specific/path/in/the/fs/sample-input.xml.
Output: /a/specific/path/in/the/fs/sample-input.xml: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1


Second case


Command: /a/specific/path/$ file -i in/the/fs/sample-input.xml.
Output: in/the/fs/sample-input.xml: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Is somebody able to explain the difference for both charsets since the command is reading the same file?

What does ls -i /a/specific/path/in/the/fs/sample-input.xml in/the/fs/sample-input.xml report? One thing I can think of is that while you're already in /a/specific/path, some parent directory might have been mounted over, so while you can still access the original contents by virtue of being already in it, any access via the full path would use the mounted data.

Hi, thanks for the feedback, the idea is smart! Sadly,I have no mount on the file system. The output is something like 4888081 in/the/fs/sample-input.xml.

I forgot to say that both ls -i gave the same inode info.
